# Flutter bloc doesn't showing UI as per proper state

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Am using flutter bloc library and maintaining simple process for as per library for state management. In this code I am getting the state as expected but UI is not updating, its always returning the default state ui which a circle spinner [image: circle spinner]. I have checked the state using bloc observer too. [image] So need to know that what I have done wrong and need suggestions on that.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          BlocBuilder<UserManageCubit, UserManageState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is Initial) {
                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ));
              }

              if (state is UserDetailFetched) {
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '${state.userDetails.name}'.toUpperCase(),
                      style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 18.sp,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${state.userDetails.email}',
                      style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${state.userDetails.phone}',
                      style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Registered on ${DateTimeUtils.format(
                        DateTimeUtils.fromString(state.userDetails.createdAt!),
                      ).split("-")[0]}',
                      style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: go11ThemeGreen,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.h),
                  ],
                );
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.amber,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Calling bloc

```
@override
  void initState() {
    
    BlocProvider.of<UserManageCubit>(context).getUserDetails(widget.userId);
    super.initState();
  }
```

#Cubit impl

```
UserManageCubit({required this.userManageRepo})
      : super(const UserManageState.initial());


  void getUserDetails(int userId) async {
    final FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'user_id': userId,
    });

    final Either<Failure, UserDetailsResponse> userDetailResponseEither =
        await userManageRepo.getUserDetails(formData);

    emit(const UserManageState.loading());

    userDetailResponseEither.fold(
        (failure) => {
              emit(
                UserManageState.loadFailure(
                  errorObject:
                      ErrorObject.mapFailureToErrorObject(failure: failure),
                ),
              )
            },
        (response) => {
              emit(
                UserManageState.userDetailFetched(
                    userDetails: response.userDetails),
              ),
            });
  }
```

#state class

```
@freezed
class UserManageState with _$UserManageState {
  const factory UserManageState.initial() = Initial;
  const factory UserManageState.loading() = Loading;

  const factory UserManageState.loadFailure({
    required ErrorObject errorObject,
  }) = LoadFailure;

  const factory UserManageState.userDetailFetched(
      {required UserDetails userDetails,
      @Default(0) int currentDocType,
      @Default(0) int currentCancelType}) = UserDetailFetched;

  
  
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your cubit/bloc implementation

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Hi Ozan, I have added that in question. Plase have a look

Comment: Can you include `UserManageState`

Comment: You are checking if the state is of type UserDetailFetched but you are returning UserManageState from the cubit. That's why your code isn't working.

Comment: @Creator I didn't understand what you said. UderDetailFetched is state of UserManageState cubit.

Comment: I didnt use freezed for State, is it ok If I use equatable

Comment: UserManageState.userDetailFetched . It is a named constructor rite?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh that is totally okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning your column

```
 if (state is UserDetailFetched) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '${state.userDetails.name}'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 18.sp,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${state.userDetails.email}',
                          style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${state.userDetails.phone}',
                          style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Registered on ${DateTimeUtils.format(
                            DateTimeUtils.fromString(state.userDetails.createdAt!),
                          ).split("-")[0]}',
                          style: kNavyTextStyleNormal.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: go11ThemeGreen,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 16.h),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
```

Comment: Glad I can help, I experienced it early on in my career so once I saw it I was like "oh".